# Add Google Analytics to site hosted on Adobe Business Catalyst?

Tags: google-analytics

I inherited an Adobe BC site.  I've poked around the admin interface but am failing to figure out how I should add Google's analystic scripts to the site.  I gather that BC sites are rendered, so I'm assuming there's a template *somewhere* I can stick it in, but I've had no luck finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the code in the head section to the master/main template (try Home page → Page properties → Metadata → HTML for <head>))